# I wanted to get the language which has the highest average rating in pyspark

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have connected MongoDB in pyspark notebook in databricks and then

```
rating.createOrReplaceTempView("rat")
```

Using this used spark SQL

```
lan = spark.sql("select language from (select language, avg(imdbRating), max(avg(imdbRating)) as m from rat group by language) group by language having avg(imdbRating) = m").show()
```

and it is throwing this error:

> Analysis exception: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.;;

Any idea where I am going wrong.

EDIT:
The result is as

```
+--------------------+
|            language|
+--------------------+
|English, Dutch, F...|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery and assign ranks to get the language with max rating:

```
lan = spark.sql("""
    select language 
    from (
        select language, rank() over (order by avg_rating desc) as rn 
        from (
            select language, avg(imdbRating) as avg_rating
            from rat 
            group by language
        )
    ) where rn = 1
""")
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked but the result is coming in a single row and I tried using row_number() but that didn't work how do I get those results in different rows?

Comment: what do you mean different rows? could you please elaborate using an example?

Comment: The result is coming in a single row like English, French, Hindi etc what I want is that they should appear in separate rows.

Comment: @RishiPandey are you sure that each line in the rat table has only a single language?

Comment: well, the code above does not perform any aggregation on the language column, so if you're getting multiple languages on a line, there might be something wrong in the other parts of your code.